# Realizar uma Query String

Tags: string, query

Pessoal tenho o seguinte método e Query:

```
mt_dispositivo = MtDispositivo
    .where("id_conta = 28 or id_conta = 29 or id_conta = 30 or id_conta = 36")
    .select('nome, data_criacao, data_atualizacao, tipo_conexao, is_online, status_atualizacao, geolocalizacao_endereco')   

    send_data mt_dispositivo.to_xls(:except => [:id_conta], content_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: 'mt_dispositivo.xls')
```

Este método faz um Download Excel como ID e outros atributos de todos
 os Clientes que estiverem Online. Preciso fazer uma query String que me retorne apenas os que contêm no
 inicio: "BS, FS, SR e FNAC"

Como ficaria?

Comment: A que linguagem se refere a pergunta?

Comment: Linguagem Ruby.